# I wants to apply Ajax on all my contents in a modal, but it is working only on first modal element in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am facing issue in Ajax its only work for first element in a loop not on other elements.When i select an item in dropdown the Ajax function is called and populate the fields only for first modal section in a loop not for other sections. kindly answer this question.

I have applied many techniques using Ajax but non succeed

``````
<div class="modal fade" id="editaddon-{{$item['id']}}">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
         <!-- Modal Header -->
         <div class="modal-header">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
         </div>
         <!-- Modal body -->

         <div class="modal-body">

````DropDown Section:`````

        <div class="modal fade getid" data-id="{{$item['id']}}"  id="editaddon-{{$item['id']}}">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
         <!-- Modal Header -->
         <div class="modal-header">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
         </div>
         <!-- Modal body -->
         <div class="modal-body">
             <h1>{{$item['id']}}</h1>
             <form class="form form-horizontal" method="post" >
                 @csrf
                 <div class="form-body">
                     <h4 class="form-section"><i class="ft-user"></i>Dish Addon form</h4>
                     <div class="form-group row">
                         <label class="col-md-3 label-control" for="projectinput6">Addons Name</label>
                         <div class="col-md-9">
                             <select  name="dish_addon" class="form-control selectaddon-{{$item['id']}}">
                                 <option value="none" selected >Select Menu</option>
                                 @foreach($add_items as $add_item)
                                 @if($add_item['dish_id']==$item['id'])
                                 <option value="{{$add_item['id']}}">{{$add_item['name']}}</option>
                                 @endif
                                 @endforeach
                             </select>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </form>
             <form class="form form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{route('update.dish.addon',$addon->id)}}">
                 @csrf
                 <div class="form-body">
                     <h4 class="form-section"><i class="ft-user"></i>Dish Addon form</h4>
                     <div class="form-group row">
                         <label class="col-md-3 label-control" for="projectinput1">Addon Name</label>
                         <div class="col-md-9">
                             <input type="text"  value="" class="form-control addname-{{$item['id']}}" placeholder="Addon Name"
                                 name="name">
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group row">
                         <label class="col-md-3 label-control" for="projectinput2">Addon Price</label>
                         <div class="col-md-9">
                             <input type="text"  value="" class="form-control addprice-{{$item['id']}}" placeholder="Addon Price"
                                 name="price">
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-md-1">
                             <input type="text"  value="" class="form-control dishadd-{{$item['id']}}" placeholder="Addon Price"
                                 name="add">
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-actions">
                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                         <i class="la la-check-square-o"></i> Save
                         </button>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </form>
         </div>

      ````the Ajax function include in dish_script````

         @include('dish.dish_script')
         <!-- Modal footer -->
         <div class="modal-footer">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
`````end of loop:

`````Ajax Sction````

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var x=jQuery('.getid').attr('data-id');
console.log(x);
jQuery('.selectaddon-'+x).change(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.ajaxSetup({
headers: {
'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '<?php echo csrf_token() ?>'
}
});
jQuery.ajax({
url: "{{ route('edit.dish.addon') }}",
method: 'post',
data: {
dish_addon: jQuery('.selectaddon-'+x).val(),
},
dataType:'JSON',
success: function(result){
if( result.success == 'true')
{
var data = result.data;
$('.addname-'+x).val(data.name);
$('.addprice-'+x).val(data.price);
$('.dishadd-'+x).val(data.id);
}
}
});
});
});

When i select dropdown both fields populated with data its only working on first modal in a loop not in others.
``````

Comment: It's because element id's in a page must be unique by definition. Use classes and traverse within modal instance

Comment: Yes i have changed ids into classes and traversed in a loop but nothing changed

Comment: Need to see updated code

Comment: sorry to disturb you but i am unable to post my updated code, can you edit  above code so i can apply it on my project

Comment: can you tell me what i need to traverse in modal instance ,after i changed my ids into classes . I have also put my script in modal  and traverse it but nothing happened

Comment: Ahsan, If you can't edit, you can delete this question and re-ask with the new code.